# Display options question

Tags: display, display-resolution

My display is a Sony xbr-x850b, which supposedly has a resolution of 3840x2160 at 16:9, but in Ubuntu Settings > Displays there's an option to display 4096x2160 at 9:5. Does this mean my TV is stronger and better than I thought?

When I select 4096x2160 at 9:5 it works, but my desktop loses about 2.5 inches in height, a black bar appears on top and on bottom, and I get the following outputs on command:

```
    ~$ xdpyinfo | grep dots
              resolution: 96x96 dots per inch
    ~$ xrandr | grep -w connected
     HDMI-0 connected primary 4096x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1220mm x 680mm
```

But when I select 3840x2160 at 16:9, my desktop is the full size of the screen and I get the following output on command:

```
    :~$ xrandr | grep -w connected 
    HDMI-0 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1220mm x 680mm
    :~$ xdpyinfo | grep dots
                 resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that your GPU is powerful enough to provide you with the option of using a resolution up to 4096 x 2160.

Given your the result you get on your display when selecting the mode, I'd say:

#### Unfortunately, your display is not up to par with your GPU :'(